# ArgoCD Ingress Kubernetes Too Many Redirects even With --insecure - Nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I have followed the quickstart of ArgoCD documentation https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#quick-start

The only difference is that I deployed in `argo-cd` namespace instead of `argocd`.

Now, I'm having issues to access this application through my Nginx ingress. It's throwing `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on the browser and in the logs of Nginx:

```
172.71.6.219 - - [05/Jul/2023:23:01:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 308 164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 904 0.000 [argo-cd-argocd-server-http] [] - - - - ba62103809faf5da2f9e2661a2c1f50b
172.71.6.219 - - [05/Jul/2023:23:01:54 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 308 164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 904 0.000 [argo-cd-argocd-server-http] [] - - - - 0d05a1f48fdceb5d4c557884c3850074
172.71.6.219 - - [05/Jul/2023:23:01:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 308 164 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 904 0.000 [argo-cd-argocd-server-http] [] - - - - d724f5d890ce91e713c768db2126d44f
.......... more and more
```

On the ArgoCD server, I've setted the `server.insecure:"true"` on `argocd-cmd-params-cm`.

This is my Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress
  namespace: argo-cd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: prod-issuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: OriginIssuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: cert-manager.k8s.cloudflare.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.my_site.dev'
    secretName: argocd-secret
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: argocd.my_site.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              name: http
```

I've tried to set  `server.insecure:"false"` and my Ingress like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress
  namespace: argo-cd
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: prod-issuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: OriginIssuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: cert-manager.k8s.cloudflare.com
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.my_site.dev'
    secretName: argocd-secret
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: argocd.my_site.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              name: https
```

PS: Of course I've deleted the argo-cd-server between the changes on the ConfigMap.

Nothing is working.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` is an error message, a browser returns when it fails to load webpage content due to a redirect loop.  A redirect loop occurs when a requested page redirects to another page and the second page redirects back to the origin. Follow this [Link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) for redirecting the Path and add the below annotation in yaml and it will help in overcoming this error.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```